# Bonding and symmetry

Tags: group-theory

So I have been looking at different ways of symmetry and bonding
The so called counting method is something that I don't get

For each operation in the group:

```
For each object in the basis set:

    Apply the operation to the object to generate a resultant object
    Calculate the overlap between the resultant object and the object
Sum the overlaps to give the character for the operation.
```

You get +1 if the orbitals stays the same zero if it moves and - 1 if it changes I find it hard to imagine the AO not really sure if the method works perhaps someone here can show en example.

Comment: You should improve the quality of your question. To begin with, it is difficult to understand what your starting point is, and what you understand or misunderstand. Are you familiar with matrix representations, reducible representations and ireducible representations? Guess you are asking about symmetry-adapted linear combinations of molecular orbitals (SALC). You need to work on your basic concepts and improbe your question. You can find useful information and examples on Molecular Symmetry form the PhysChem or InorgChem point of wie at [Libretext.org Chemistry] (https://chem.libretexts.org)

Answer (score 0):

Ive attached a figure that should help, in this case for a rotation. This only works for 90/180 rotation/reflection for any other angle you need to use sin/cosine. The procedure is the same for orbitals as for atoms as shown here.

[image: symmetry]